# How to retrieve value between two similar chars

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, charindex

I have following sample data and the query I have tried so far -

```
DECLARE @X TABLE (TAG VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @X 
VALUES ('59D:$%$%$%$%^MESSAGE1^$%$%$%$%'),
       ('59D:--^MESSAGE2^$%$%$%$%')

SELECT * 
FROM @X

SELECT SUBSTRING(TAG,CHARINDEX('^',TAG)+1,LEN(TAG)-CHARINDEX('^',TAG))
FROM @X;
```

I want to select everything **between** `^`. So in this case, my output should be `MESSAGE1` and `MESSAGE2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
substring(tag,charindex('^',tag)+1, len(tag) - charindex('^',reverse(tag)) - charindex('^',tag))
from @x
```

You might also want to exclude cases when there are less than 2 `^` in the string. In that case, you should add a `where` clause

```
WHERE len(tag) - len(replace(tag,'^','')) >= 2
```